# Update Bootstrap Popover Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an indicator that pops over whenever the input text is focused. The content of the popover is html.

**JS**

```
$('.validate').popover({
    html : true,
    trigger : 'focus',
    content : function() {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
});
```

**On Change**

```
$('.validate').change(function() {
    var eval_me = $('.validate').val();
    $('#sample').html(eval_me);
});
```

**The HTML**

```
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span><input type="text" class="validate" data-placement='right' title="Hello World">
    </div>

    <div id="popover-content" style="display: none">
        <div class="row"><label id="sample">This is your div content</label></div>
    </div>
```

The content inside the label gets updated, but the popover isn't. Dismissing the popover and focusing  the input text again (to open it) shows the updated label.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: how are you activating your popover? Also, throwing this in a jsFiddle or codepen will help

Comment: it's activated when the input is focused, did it when I initialized the popover `trigger : 'focus'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: the `change` event doesn't fire until the input loses focus, you probably want to bind the update code to the `keyup` event. Second, though that code *is* updating your `sample` div, the popover is just getting that data when the popover is triggered; if you want to update the popover's `sample` div, you need to handle that as part of the `keyup` event handler. Try changing that event handler like so:

```
$('.validate').keyup(function() {
  var eval_me = $('.validate').val();
  $('#sample').html(eval_me);
  $('.popover #sample').html(eval_me);
});
```

and you should be good. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/rK34t/).

**Edit**: actually playing with it a little, it seems like `keyup` is a better trigger than `keypress`, otherwise the update trails the input by one char, but I'm probably just missing something there. Changed the code above accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, figured it had something to do with `change` not being fired! Thanks!

Comment: Also I just noticed that you might want to make `sample` a class instead of an id so that you're not ending up with duplicate ids, 'cuz that ain't right.